# Saving Multiple HTML files in R

Tags: r, reactjs, leaflet, visualization

I am following this R tutorial here (towards the end of the page) : https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/examples.html. I would like to make an interactive map that allows you to filter points on the map - i.e. when you click on the table rows, points on the map appear and disappear.

I decided to generate my own data for this problem. I am following the last part where they make a map/table:

```
library(leaflet)
library(htmltools)
library(crosstalk)
library(reactable)
library(htmlwidgets)

myFun <- function(n = 5000) {
  a <- do.call(paste0, replicate(5, sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE), FALSE))
  paste0(a, sprintf("%04d", sample(9999, n, TRUE)), sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE))
}

 id = 1:1000
long = 2.2945 + rnorm( 1000, 0.1085246 , 0.1)
lat = 48.8584 + rnorm( 1000, 0.009036273 , 0.1)

my_data_1 = data.frame(id, lat, long, var1 = myFun(1000), var2 = myFun(1000), var3 = myFun(1000) )
```

Then, I manipulated the data according

```
brew_sp <- SharedData$new(my_data_1, group = "breweries")

brew_data <- as_tibble(my_data_1) %>%
  select(var1, var2, var3) %>%
  SharedData$new(group = "breweries")
```

I then tried to make the map (I added a small change to the map):

```
   map  <- leaflet(brew_sp) %>%
  addTiles() %>% 
      addMarkers(clusterOption=markerClusterOptions())
```

And then the table:

```
tbl <- reactable(
  brew_data ,
  selection = "multiple",

  filterable = TRUE,
  searchable = TRUE,
  onClick = "select",
  rowStyle = list(cursor = "pointer"),
  minRows = 10
)
```

Then, I put them together and saved the result - this worked fine:

```
   final_file = htmltools::browsable(
      htmltools::tagList(map, tbl)
    )



htmltools::save_html(tagList(map, tbl), file = "sample.html")
```

**However, here is the problem:**

I noticed that when I click on only one of the rows, I notice that everything else still appears on the map. Shouldn't all the other points disappear when only one item is selected?

- Could someone show me how to make this map/table look the same way it appears in the tutorial?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: FYI: The dataset used in the tutorial is a dataset from the `leaflet` package. See `?leaflet::breweries91`

Comment: While there are some differences in your code compared to the tutorial the decisive one is `clusterOption=markerClusterOptions()`. When you remove that you get your desired result as in the tutorial.

Comment: @ stefan: thank you for your comments! Is it not possible to use "markerClusterOptions" along with this?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not an expert in `leaflet`. So I don't know whether this is possible. But there is a related issue on GitHub https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/478 from which I would suspect that  it's not possible as of the moment.

Comment: @ Stefan: thank you ! I will keep this in mind!